# Looping through my lists to display the information on an .xml

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create a duplicate copy of a .xml and need to present it like (with info placed where needed):

```html
    <FMEA>
      <Component>
        <Name></Name>
          <BasicEvent ID="">
            <Name></Name>
            <ShortName></ShortName>
            <Description></Description>
            <Unavailability></Unavailability>
          </BasicEvent>
          <BasicEvent ID="">
            <Name></Name>
            <ShortName></ShortName>
            <Description></Description>
            <Unavailability></Unavailability>
          </BasicEvent>
          <BasicEvent ID="">
            <Name></Name>
            <ShortName></ShortName>
            <Description></Description>
            <Unavailability></Unavailability>            
          </BasicEvent>
        //And so on...
      </Component>   
    </FMEA>
```

I'm sure I've made the classes right, but I'm not to sure how to loop through the lists that I've created to place the information in the correct place. My code id below and I'd really appreciate any help you lot can offer. Thanks - K

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ACW
{
class Program
{
    const string FILENAME = @"SmallResults.xml";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
        FMEA fmea = new FMEA();
        fmea.comps = doc.Descendants("FMEA").Select(x => new Component()
        {
            Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
            BasicEvent = x.Elements("BasicEvent").Select(y => BasicEvent.FindBasicEvent(y)).ToList()
        }).ToList();
        foreach(Component comp in fmea.comps)
        {
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(Component)).Serialize(Console.Out, comp);
            //I'm sure something goes here... A foreach loop or something...
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class Component
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<BasicEvent> BasicEvent { set; get; }
}
public class BasicEvent
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string ShortName { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
    public string Unavalability { set; get; }

    public static BasicEvent FindBasicEvent(XElement BasicEvent)
    {
        BasicEvent NewBasicEvent = new BasicEvent();
        NewBasicEvent.Name = (string)BasicEvent.Element("Name");
        NewBasicEvent.ShortName = (string)BasicEvent.Element("ShortName");
        NewBasicEvent.Description = (string)BasicEvent.Element("Description");
        NewBasicEvent.Unavalability = (string)BasicEvent.Element("Unavalability");
        return NewBasicEvent;
    }
}
class FMEA
{
    public List<Component> comps { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: How about [*Serializing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) your FMEA class. (It may need some changes in your model)

Comment: @L.B Sorry I'm really new to this, how would this be done??

Comment: Google `c# XmlSerializer`

Comment: Generate an XSD schema from your XML, then convert the XSD schema into C# classes using xsd.exe or Xsd2Code, then import the class into your project and with the help of XmlSerializer you can easily create what you are doing.

Comment: @Peroxy how about using VS's `Edit/Paste Special/Paste Xml as Classes`? Much easier...

Comment: @L.B I never knew this existed, but even still I have the same problem... How do i then run through and output a duplicate file??

Answer (score -1):

what is difficult about duplicating an xml?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XDocument duplicate = XDocument.Parse(doc.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the data later on

Comment: See following posting.  I did this recently in vb.net but have done it a lot of times also in c# with similar code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549576/duplicate-xml-object-multiple-times-while-incrementing-attribute-value/40553880#comment68450390_40553880